# c# regex only first match in each sentence

Tags: c#, regex

I almost had my regex but then I got a problem I cant get fixed.

Sentence:

> oListView.sTranslatedPrintHeader =
>      Dictionary.gsTranslate(oClientInfo, "Lastschriftenstapel") & " " &
>      DataMethods.gsGetDBValue(oClientInfo, "BatchDesc",
>      "tdDebitAdviceBatches", "BatchID=" & lBatchID)
>
> Response.Write(Dictionary.gsTranslate(oClientinfo,"Es konnten keine
>      Befehle in der Auswahl dargestellt werden,
> " & _  "das Design kann
>      trotzdem modifiziert werden."))

Regex:

```
(?<=[D-d]ictionary\.gs[T-t]ranslate.*?, ?)( ?")((.|\n|\r)*?"\))
```

Example & output: https://regexr.com/4rpfj

So my first match is ok, but my regex doesn't stop in that sentence and continues and then matches

> "BatchDesc", "tdDebitAdviceBatches", "BatchID=" & lBatchID)
>
> Response.Write(Dictionary.gsTranslate(oClientinfo,"Es konnten keine
>      Befehle in der Auswahl dargestellt werden,
> " & _  "das Design kann
>      trotzdem modifiziert werden.")

What matches I want

```
"Lastschriftenstapel")
```

And

```
"Es konnten keine Befehle in der Auswahl dargestellt werden,<br>" & _ "das Design kann trotzdem modifiziert werden.")
```

**Little note:** there is a whole file with multiple matches. So I don't want the first match in the text, I want the first match after every `Dictionary.gsTranslate`.

Comment: Does `(?<=(?i)dictionary\.gstranslate(?-i)\([^)]+, *)"[^)]+"` work for you?

Comment: @ctwheels perfect! thank you

Comment: I converted it to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

[See regex in use here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3fi%29dictionary%5c.gstranslate%5c%28%5b%5e%29%5d%2b%2c+*%29%22%5b%5e%29%5d%2b%22&i=oListView.sTranslatedPrintHeader+%3d+Dictionary.gsTranslate%28oClientInfo%2c+%22Lastschriftenstapel%22%29+%26+%22+%22+%26+DataMethods.gsGetDBValue%28oClientInfo%2c+%22BatchDesc%22%2c+%22tdDebitAdviceBatches%22%2c+%22BatchID%3d%22+%26+lBatchID%29%0d%0a%0d%0aResponse.Write%28Dictionary.gsTranslate%28oClientinfo%2c%22Es+konnten+keine+Befehle+in+der+Auswahl+dargestellt+werden%2c%0d%0a%22+%26+_+%22das+Design+kann+trotzdem+modifiziert+werden.%22%29%29)

```
(?<=(?i)dictionary\.gstranslate\([^)]+, *)"[^)]+"
# or the following with RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
(?<=dictionary\.gstranslate\([^)]+, *)"[^)]+"
```

How it works:

- `(?<=(?i)dictionary\.gstranslate\([^)]+, *)` positive lookbehind ensuring the following precedes

  - `(?i)` enables case-insensitive flag
  - `dictionary\.gstranslate` matches `dictionary.gstranslate` literally (case-insensitive)
  - `\(` match `(` literally
  - `[^)]+` match any character except `)` one or more times
  - `, *` matches comma literally, then any number of spaces
- `"[^)]+"` matches `"`, then any character except `)` one or more times, then `"`

Comment: `(?-i)` makes no difference, there are no letters to match after it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, the \n|\r is allowing the match to include and go past the "BatchDesc"... Since line-break continuation should occur with the underscore character (from what I see in your text) perhaps this would suit your need:

```
(?<=[D-d]ictionary\.gs[T-t]ranslate.*?, ?)("(.|\_ ?\n|\_ ?\r)*?"(?=\)))
```

I just added the mandatory underscore before the \n and \r.

https://regexr.com/4rrv0

Comment: I get an error: ``System.ArgumentException: 'parsing "(?<=[D-d]ictionary\.gs[T-t]ranslate.*?, ?")((.|\_ ?\n|\_ ?\r)*?"\))" - Unrecognized escape sequence \_.'
`` I am using c# like my tag tells me, any fix for me?

Comment: @NielsLucas For all occurrences of `\_` you need to escape them. Change them to `\\_`.

Comment: @Kit ah thanks! I will try that later today, even tho I have an answere already, I wanna try other solutions as well.